# Conditionally changing the label of a navigation bar item to a shorter label results in incorrect alignment

Tags: ios, swiftui

When switching the navigation bar item label from a longer label to a shorter one, the new, shorter, label will be aligned at the center of the old label, as in the two images below:

[image]

[image]

This is the code for the problem:

```
struct NavBarItemIssueView: View {
    @State private var isLargeView = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Some text")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    self.isLargeView.toggle()
                }) {
                    if self.isLargeView == true {
                        Text("Show small label")
                    } else {
                        Text("Small")

                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

In the app I am making I have to switch between two labels when the edit mode is enabled or disabled and this problem occurs. Is there a way to fix this alignment in swift(ui)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a frame on your button with `minWidth` that is about the width of your biggest button, then you can align the button to the leading edge:

```swift
        NavigationView {
            Text("Some text")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    self.isLargeView.toggle()
                }) {
                    if self.isLargeView == true {
                        Text("Show small label")
                    } else {
                        Text("Small")

                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 200, alignment: .leading)
            )
        }
```